# passing class or datareader via webservice

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have a broad question about Web Services and SOA.  I have a database that contains data I would like to expose for reading (just reading, no inserts or updates).  Is it best to expose the data as a class or is it best to expose the information as a datareader?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't expose data reader over web service. You have to execute reader, fill data to objects and send those objects.

Check WCF Data services. It will save you a lot of work.

Comment: thank you, is it better to return a class or primitive data types

Comment: @css-bp: well, if you need more than just a string, you almost have to create a serializable class to handle your data....

Answer (score 1):

I think the DataReader is not serializable. It's better to return the result as list of objects or you may fill a DataTable and return it.